# How to download credentials.json in Gmail API Enable Java

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, google-developers-console

I am trying to enable [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) following steps in [Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java). When I click on `"Enable the Gmail API"` button in the Google developer console, no option like "Download Client Configuration" is displayed.

So, I am unable to get credentials.json File.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the SO club. Try to update your question and make it a bit more clear. Also please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)! Thanks.

Comment: @Yasen the question is quite clear.  I added a few links to his question it should be clearer now.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58460476/where-to-find-credentials-json-for-google-api-client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gmail API credentials are restricted to enhance apps security. To enable the credentials click on `API Console` after clicking on `Enable the Gmail API`. You will travel to a filled form on the `Credentials` menu on `Google APIs`. You can change there the name and/or restrictions to better suit your project. Finally, you can click on `Generate key` to finish the process.

If you have followed the steps so far, you would have created the Gmail API credentials. To achieve your request you will need to click on `Download JSON` button on the right side of your newly created credentials. Do not hesitate to ask for more information if I haven't explained the process with enough detail.

Answer (score 2):

Just enabling the Gmail api isnt going to create client credential for you. Unfortunately the developer console changes more often then the quick starts get updated so it can be difficult to understand.

Go to the https://console.developers.google.com

Find the credentials tab on the left and click the `Create credentials` button

[image]

You are probably going to be looking for an oauth client id, as service accounts only work with gmail if you are connecting to a gsuite account.

Answer (score 1):

now that it's been changed you must click edit credentials and then head over to the keys tab. Once you're there you can generate a key in any form of the file you want. So just click.json and it should be active and downloaded.